# Java servlet handling its own outputted HTML form

Tags: html, servlets, request, response

I am still new to Java and I find that by far the aspect taking longest to understand is servlets.

I am busy writing a servlet that must initially show an HTML form (if a FORM is actually needed here), in which
the user enters a monetary amount into a text field.

There are 3 buttons underneath the textfield: Balance, Deposit and Withdraw.

Deposit: adds the amount in the textfield to the total "bank account" of the user.
Withdraw: subtracts the amount in the textfield from the total "bank account" of the user.
Balance: displays the current remaining total of the "bank account" just under the textfield.

What is unusual is that in this task, they require me to only use a servlet to address all these things.

So the servlet HTMLBank.java must do the following:

- Display form with textfield for entering an amount, a line for showing the current remaining total of the bank
  account, and the abovementioned buttons doing the said actions.
- Add entered amount to the account total, via appropriate button's input.
- Subtract entered amount from the total, via appropriate button's input.
- Show to the screen the current remaining total of bank account, via appropriate button's input.

So, where it's common to use a separate HTML document as the form page, and have its submission redirect the
browser to the separate servlet file for data processing, here I have to make the servlet write that form, as well
as take its input and then show the described output - all on the same Web page.

And this is where I am confused as to how to achieve this. Firstly, these buttons I coded and assigned methods to,
do not work. I click them but nothing happens. Help on the buttons would be also appreciated.

The following is the updated code of my HTMLBank.java servlet (this is nothing confidential as it's not actually linked
to any real bank account. Just a textbook task.):

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class HTMLBank extends HttpServlet
{
    double balance;

    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        balance = 0;
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        request.setAttribute("formattedBal", formatBalance());

        out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<hr>");
            out.println("<title>Online Bank ATM Simulator</title>");
            out.println("<h1 align = \"center\">Bank ATM Simulation</h1>");
            out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<form method = \"GET\" action = \"HTMLBank\">");
                    out.println("<center>");
                    out.println("Amount: ");
                    out.println("<input type = \"text\" name = \"amount\" id = \"amount\" size = \"20\"><br><br>");
                    out.println("Balance: ");
                    out.println((String)request.getAttribute("formattedBal") + "<br><br>");
                    out.println("<button name = \"balButton\" value = \"Balance\">Balance</button>");
                    out.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                    out.println("<button name = \"depButton\" value = \"Deposit\">Deposit</button>");
                    out.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                    out.println("<button name = \"withdrButton\" value = \"Withdraw\">Withdraw</button>");
                    out.println("</center>");
                out.println("</form>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("<hr>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "Tues, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if(request.getParameter("depButton") != null && request.getParameter("depButton").equals("Deposit"))
        {
            if(verifyAmount(request))
            {
                addToBalance(request);
                clearDisplay(request);

                request.setAttribute("formattedBal", formatBalance());

                out.println("<html>");
                    out.println("<hr>");
                    out.println("<title>Online Bank ATM Simulator</title>");
                    out.println("<h1 align = \"center\">Bank ATM Simulation</h1>");
                    out.println("<body>");
                        out.println("<form method = \"GET\" action = \"HTMLBank\">");
                            out.println("<center>");
                            out.println("Amount: ");
                            out.println("<input type = \"text\" name = \"amount\" id = \"amount\" size = \"20\"><br><br>");
                            out.println("Balance: ");
                            out.println((String)request.getAttribute("formattedBal") + "<br><br>");
                            out.println("<button name = \"balButton\" value = \"Balance\">Balance</button>");
                            out.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                            out.println("<button name = \"depButton\" value = \"Deposit\">Deposit</button>");
                            out.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                            out.println("<button name = \"withdrButton\" value = \"Withdraw\">Withdraw</button>");
                            out.println("</center>");
                        out.println("</form>");
                    out.println("</body>");
                    out.println("<br>");
                    out.println("<hr>");
                out.println("</html>");
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("<html>");
                    out.println("<head>");
                        out.println("<title>Amount Input Error</title>");
                    out.println("</head>");

                    out.println("<body>");
                        out.println("<h1>Error processing the input.</h1><br><br>");
                        out.println("Please ensure your input:<br><br>");
                        out.println("- Is strictly a number.");
                        out.println("- Is a positive, non-zero amount.");
                    out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
            }
        }

        if(request.getParameter("withdrButton") != null && request.getParameter("withdrButton").equals("Withdraw"))
        {
            if(verifyAmount(request))
            {
                subtractFromBalance(request);
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("<html>");
                    out.println("<head>");
                        out.println("<title>Amount Input Error</title>");
                    out.println("</head>");

                    out.println("<body>");
                        out.println("<h1>Error processing the input.</h1><br><br>");
                        out.println("Please ensure your input:<br><br>");
                        out.println("- Is strictly a number.");
                        out.println("- Is a positive, non-zero amount.");
                    out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
            }
        }

        if(request.getParameter("balButton") != null && request.getParameter("balButton").equals("Balance"))
        {
            showBalance(request, response);
        }
    }

    public boolean verifyAmount(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        boolean amountValid = false;

        if(request.getParameter("amount") != "" && Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("amount")) > 0)
            amountValid = true;
        else
            amountValid = false;

        return amountValid;
    }

    public void addToBalance(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        double userAmount = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("amount"));
        balance = balance + userAmount;
    }

    public void subtractFromBalance(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        double userAmount = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("amount"));
        balance = balance + userAmount;
    }

    public void showBalance(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {

    }

    public String formatBalance()
    {
        DecimalFormat dollars = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.###");
        String formattedAmount = dollars.format(balance);
        return formattedAmount;
    }

    public void clearDisplay(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        request.setAttribute("amount", "");
        request.setAttribute("formattedBal", "");
    }

    public void destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

The part I'm unsure of is how to code the same servlet to create a form, then use its own form's input and respond
back to that same Web page. The operations - deposit, withdraw, balance display - are to run as many times as the
user desires.

For now ignore all custom-defined methods and only look at addToBalance() (and if needed, the methods it calls), as I
am first trying to get this one function to work as needed. When I succeed, I'll code other functions similarly,
except the difference in the arithmetic operations.

To explain what needs to happen, using the function I'm trying to get to work right now:

1) Initially form appears with "Balance: $0" displayed and and empty textbox labeled "Amount:".
2) The user enters money amount and clicks "Deposit". The servlet must redisplay the form, but
the "$0" and the textfield must be cleared. Invisible to user, the entered amount is added to the balance.
3) If the user clicks "Balance", the page must redisplay, showing the current balance as "Balance: $xxx" and the
textfield must once again be cleared.

The problem is that when I run the servlet per above code, enter an amount and click "Deposit", the only thing that
happens is the textfield clears, but the "$0" remains shown. I.e. the button does not work as intended.

I appreciate your help a lot! Thanks.

Comment: I would split up the form generation from the form processing.  Use `doGet` as the first part of your method - to _get_ the form.  Use `doPost` to process the form _post_.  Start with that and use the browser debugging tools to make sure the HTML looks right and that it is sending back what you expect.

Comment: Hey, stdunbar.

Thank you for the rapid response, I will follow the suggestions and let know of developments as I go.

Comment: stdunbar, I have worked on this servlet and updated the post with new code, which incorporates your advice above too. I also describe the required performance of the servlet. If you and anybody could read it now and point me in the right direction I'd be infinitely obliged to you. :)

Comment: Have you learned about redirects yet?  It's still a bit more complicated than needed.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply - I actually solved the whole problem. The issue was: the HTML form had the method set to GET, while the method that would respond to the submitted form is doPost(). I changed the method designation in the form tag to POST and all works. Thank you!